# Does the Pixel C Now Support HDMI-over-USB-C?

Tags: google-play-store, hdmi

When the Pixel C was released, we were told that [it does not support HDMI-out over its USB-C port, but that it might be enabled later](http://www.computerworld.com/article/3012782/tablets/pixel-c-deep-dive-review-a-terrific-tablet-that-tries-to-be-more.html).

However, on Google's own store, they offer [a USB-C to HDMI adapter](https://store.google.com/product/usb_type_c_to_hdmi_adapter), and the page indicates that you can "enjoy it" with the Pixel C.

So... does anyone know if the Pixel C got the update to support HDMI-out or not?

Comment: I assume you've seen this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/55ul1p/google_pixel_has_usb_30/ In that reddit thread is a link to https://plus.google.com/+BensonLeung/posts/Zpvk13X1jpj which seems to state that you need USB HDMI (or DisplayPort) Alternate Mode. All I can find is references to Chromebook Pixel 2 having USB Alternate Mode but no other devices. Leaning toward store error for Pixel C support.

Comment: @MorrisonChang: "I assume you've seen this thread" -- nope, that didn't come up in searches. Thanks! The Benson discussion seems to be about the Pixel phones, not the Pixel C (leastways, the Pixel C is not mentioned).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It doesn't; none of the Pixel devices support - it's a Google  Store goof up**

- I was helping a friend on the purchase decision of Pixel XL and lack of USB C - HDMI was a major drawback. Just to confirm we contacted Google support and they confirmed it doesn't support HDMI
- Seeing your question, I contacted them again, since there are plenty of references to *lack* of support and only Google Store confirming it supports, which is an oddity. They verbally confirmed that it is a  Store site issue and followed up on mail, confirming that they are working on fixing the error. Screenshot below

[image]

You may also wish to confirm by calling them up from the *contact us* on the store web site

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a bit old now but just stumbled upon this thread. I have tried the USB-C to displayport cable with my pixel C (after seeing "Enjoy it with Pixel C" on the google store) and it doesn't work.