# Does the Pixel 3 need an active or passive USB C to 3.5mm Adapter?

Tags: google-pixel, headphone-jack, usb-c

Does the Google Pixel 3 Phone require an active or passive USB C to 3.5mm jack adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google store doesn't sell this adapter in India but links to retailers whose product description shows it has a DAC chip and therefore  is *active* similar to [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07J28BYT9). Note that this works on Pixel 2 and [Google Support for Pixel 2](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/forum/AAAAb4-OgUsYvy0RfOPFfU/?hl=by) clearly mentions it has a DAC and  is *active*.

Comment: Pixel 3 connector specs are not made available by Google AFAIK

Comment: I got a chance to try it and the passive one doesn't work on the pixel 3. Annoying that they don't say anything anywhere.

Comment: And even when they say... It maybe wrong https://android.stackexchange.com/q/159694/131553